# C++ & XML: parsing XML in C++ working in Ubuntu Environment

Tags: c++, xml

I am working on parsing a xml file with C++ in Eclipse running under Linux Ubuntu.

Is there any free library for this?

Or any resource that I could start with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/ for my XML work in C++.  It is small, fast, and drops directly in to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I use [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) for my XML work in C++. It is small, [extremely fast](http://pugixml.org/benchmark/), drops directly to you project, and for topping it has XPath support.